# Iterate each table and get the info

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I need to get info from two tables:

> http://pastebin.com/BzbKPH2i

I iterate every table and from every table I get the info from the **td**

But I get the info two times and the **orderingText** is filled x2, so to prevent the second iteration I put a **break** to stop it but I think is not the way how it works HtmlAgilityPack or I'm doing something wrong

```
// Get the node from the div
//
HtmlNode orderingProcNode = docProcSpecs.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='orderingordering']");

string[] orderingText = new string[1024];
int t = 0;

// Iterate each table
foreach (HtmlNode orderingProcessor in orderingProcNode.SelectNodes("//table[@class='noSort infoTable']"))
{

    foreach (HtmlNode ordProcessor in orderingProcessor.SelectNodes("//tbody//tr//td"))
    {
        // Here I get all the info from the two tables instead of one table
        //
        orderingText[t++] = ordProcessor.InnerText.Trim();
    }

    break; // this is the solution
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the inner `foreach` loop - you are selecting *all* `tbody` nodes in the document, where you really want all *child nodes* of the current node - just remove the forward slashes:

```
foreach (HtmlNode ordProcessor in orderingProcessor.SelectNodes("tbody/tr/td"))
```